# Entity Framework 6 Associations not returning records

Tags: sql, entity-framework

I'm using EF6 to carve out a small data model from our ERP system. I've used this method in the past for various analytical programs with no issues. The problem I am having now is that the associations I've created don't seem to be returning all the records they are supposed to. In particular, the first two tables properly associate child records, but the third table fails to do so, returning either 1 or zero records, when in reality it should return at least two records each time. I've verified the query in SQL that rows should be returned, but when I step through the debugger, no rows are returned.

Here you can clearly see what would be my query values in the top right corner, but zero rows have been returned:
[image]

Here's a query on the same table, with the same values and it returns two rows:
[image]

Can anyone shed some light on this problem? I'm stumped and I can't figure out what the problem is. I've used EF5-6 in the past an had zero issues. My referential constraints are all setup as one to many's, as they should be. The two tables 'above' this one on the entity match and return the correct number of rows.

EF Model setup as follows, with the 'bad' association marked with an X:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. Job numbers were entered inconsistently, some with lower case letters. EF does associations strictly case sensitive, so none of my records were being associated. AFAIK there is no way around this limitation in EF, and most people seem to either build there own objects out of DB queries, or switch to NHibernate